# Concrete brick patio, -how do I temporarily divert the water around a raised deck post?

Tags: water

I am trying to fix a wet wall problem that appeared due to a incorrectly built patio. 
I am now trying to fix the under the raised deck area where the patio settled Currently the water is converging toward two of the posts of my raised deck build above the patio. Since rain is in the forecast for Tu, I need to be able to temporary divert the runoff water around these posts till I fix the problem.

Does anybody know how I can do this?

Edit: picture as requested
[image]

Comment: A picture would be very helpful.

Comment: please see the picture above. The posts are vertical, the camera distorted the angles (my phone)

Answer (score 1):

Why not create a flashing dam around the post areas?

You could use a roll of sheet aluminum, maybe 6 inches wide. Put a crease down the middle to form an **L** shape.

Scrub down the blocks and when dry, duct tape the bottom flange of the aluminum to the blocks. You can bend the corners by cutting the bottom flange to the crease or cut separate pieces and duct tape them together. Add some duct tape to the inside seam along the bottom of the well formed.

When ready, it should pull up with little to no residue. If necessary, some mineral spirits should remove any remaining adhesive.

Comment: If the tape sticks to the pavers then it would be much simpler to use a plastic sheet and the bricks that I already extracted. I can create a small dam this way...but does the tape stick to the pavers?

Comment: @user2059078 That should work as well. As to whether the tape will stick,  try it and see. It depends on how chalky the surface is. Even plastic sheeting held in place with bricks with no adhesive may be able to keep 99% of the water out if carefully placed.

Comment: I don't think that expecting the tape to work is realistic. First, it will not stick. The brick surface and the joints between bricks forming small channels will let the water go under the barrier. I think that I will use a tarp to create a sort of apron for the deck in such a way that the water will be dropped to the edge of the patio away from the deck. That edge is sloped correctly ...

Comment: Sounds like a plan. As my contractor says, the most important architectural drawings are those done on the back of an envelope by the contractor - *site specific*.